# Trim URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, templates, anchor

I'm making an ebay template for myself, and I want to use a name anchor to jump to different section on the page template.  But Ebay adds something to the URL therefore breaking the name anchor.
Since this seems to be Firefox related only, someone suggested that I need to strip "&bv=mozilla" from the URL then it would work. If there are any javascript experts out here that can help me out, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var documentUrl = location.href;
var newUrl = documentUrl.replace("&bv=mozilla","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;
```

or this:

```js
var url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + ':' + location.port + location.pathname;
```

if it is on the same page.

Otherwise, you could try this:

```js
var url = 'insert URL here';
var new_url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
```

See [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).